# SonarQube keep showing me - unit test with Angular and Jest

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, sonarqube, ts-jest

I come here because I have been working on setting up SonarQube with my Angular application for over a week.
I use jest to test my code.

Currently my problem is that my code is tested well, I obtain relevant results except on one aspect.
SonarQube does not display unit test quantity.

Below is my jest.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  verbose: false,
  maxWorkers: 10,
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!(uuid|.*ol|.*quick-lru|.*akita|.*\\.mjs$))'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'ts'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  testMatch: ['(**/*.spec.ts)'],
  testRunner: 'jest-jasmine2',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  coverageDirectory: './coverage',
  coverageReporters: ["clover", "json", "lcov", "text", "text-summary"],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    "src/**/*.ts"  // Adjust the pattern to match your project structure
  ],
  // exclude files from coverage
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/",
    "/src/main.ts",
    "/src/polyfills.ts",
    "/src/environments/environment.ts",
    "/src/environments/environment.prod.ts",
    "/src/environments/environment.azure.ts",
    "/src/app/app-routing.module.ts",
    "/src/app/app.module.ts",
    ],
  collectCoverage: true,
  testResultsProcessor: "jest-sonar-reporter",
  clearMocks: true

}
```

and below is my sonar-project.properties

```
sonar.projectKey=*******
sonar.organization=*******
sonar.projectName=*******
sonar.projectVersion=1.3.2
sonar.cpd.exclusions=src/app/login/**, src/app/register/**, src/app/dashboard-all-support/**, src/app/dashboard-all-users/**
sonar.sources=src/
sonar.tests=src/app
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**, main.ts, src/app/app.module.ts, polyfills.ts, src/main.ts, src/app/app-routing.module.ts, src/environments/environment.ts, src/environments/environment.azure.ts
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=./coverage/lcov.info
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=./coverage/lcov.info
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=./test-report.xml
sonar.typescript.tsConfigPath=./tsconfig.json
sonar.host.url=*******
```

I tried different configuration of each files, but no result.

I want SonarQube to be able to display the count of the unit test.